# Adding representation rule by object's attribute value in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.7, representation, rule

I want to add a representation rule for each object in a FeatureClass with ArcPy.

I have 3 rules (B, F, T) as seen in the picture below:

[image: Representations]

I know there is a command for it

```
representation = "Chris_Rep"
representation_rule = "F"
arcpy.CalculateRepresentationRule_cartography(in_features, representation, representation_rule)
```

But how can I classify the objects at the `in_features` attribute?

Like, if the ID of the object is less than 3, it will get "B",
and if the ID is greater than 8, it will get "T",
else it will get "F".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
If you use the `arcpy.CalculateRepresentationRule_cartography()` fucntion on your FeatureClass, it generates a `RuleID` field in the FC.
Now, you can use `SearchCursor()` with sql to filter objects:

```
sql = "FID > 3"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(featureClassPath, sql)
for row in cursor:
    print(row.getValue("RuleID"))
```

First, you get the rule number, added above ("F" or 2).
But now if you update your RuleID attribute on filtered objects:

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(featureClassPath, sql)
for ujadat in cursor:
    ujadat.setValue("RuleID", 1) # instead of 2
    cursor.updateRow(ujadat)
```

you can set the proper representation (1 or "B") to these selected (filtered) objects.